# Using 'Heading_changed' on MVCArray

Tags: model-view-controller, google-maps-api-3

How would, i'm struggling to Work out how to chage the below code to handle 'Heading_change' instead of 'Click'. Has anyone managed this? Will it still be an (event) even though there are no mouse clicks?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);

/**
 * Handles click (or other) events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
 * @param {MouseEvent} mouseEvent
 */
    function addLatLng(event) {

        var path = flightPath.getPath();

  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear
        path.push(event.latLng);

  // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
        map: map
        });alert("Done");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
```

to

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'heading_changed', addLatLng);
```

However, the heading_changed event has no MouseEvent associated with it, i.e. you can't pass in an event object to get the latLng of where the event occurred, because the  `heading_changed` event has no location associated with it.  So you'll need to rethink what you want your function to do.